# developing iOS app with WCF services

Tags: c#, .net, ios, wcf, service

I write the client app in iOS. I write the server side in WCF in Visual Studio. I use parallels to aces visual studio from my Mac. I run the service in IIS. Can I somehow acess the service from the iOS app. If I type http://127.0.0.1/ in internet explorer, it oppens IIS. But if I type http://127.0.0.1/ in safari, it doesn't recognize the address. How can I access the service from my iOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is a local loopback address. You need to put your pc's local ip address in your safari browser use ipconfig in order to find it. In order to access the services through you ios app you need to use the NSMutableURLRequest from the iOS sdk.

Comment: I went in windows(running as a virtual machine insid parallels, found it's ip using ipconfig: 10.211.55.3), typed this address in safari, ut i doesn't work